# LINQ to SQL: Group, Count, Sum. I'm so confused

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Good morning all,
     I have been stuck on this all morning and feel like I've hit a wall. I'd love any advice that can be given at this point.
 My table is basically as follows:

```
PatientName|LivingSpace
-----------|-----------
Patient 1  | Unit 1
Patient 2  | Unit 1
Patient 3  | Unit 2
Patient 4  | Unit 2
Patient 5  | Unit 3
Patient 6  | Unit 3
Patient 7  | Unit 3
Patient 8  | Unit 3
```

I need a LINQ to SQL query to illustrate this:

```
   Unit|Count
   ----|-----
Unit 1 |  2
Unit 2 |  2
Unit 3 |  4
TOTAL  |  8
```

My SQL query works fine, I'm just having issues with converting it to LINQ:

```
SELECT LivingSpace, COUNT(LivingSpace) AS LivingSpace
FROM PatientTable
WHERE Status = 'Active'
GROUP BY LivingSpace
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SUM' LivingSpace, COUNT(LivingSpace)
    FROM PatientTable
```

Comment: Just ignore the naming conventions. I changed the names as to not reflect any information.

Comment: `Groupby(x=>x.LivingSpace,(x,y)=>new{ Unit = x , Count = y.Count()});` and to get total you can do `previousQuery.Sum(x=>x.Count);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var counts = from x in ctx.PatientTable
      group x by x.LivingSpace into y
      select new { Key = y.Key Count = y.Count() };

var total  = new { Key = "Total" , Count = ctx.PatientTable.Count() };

var full = counts.ToList();

full.Add(total);
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you so much for your help. It was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it all in one query the following should work (adjusting for the actual names of your properties of course).

```
context.PatientTable.GroupBy(a => a.LivingSpace.Name, a => 1)
    .Select(a => new 
        {
            a.Key, 
            Total = a.Sum(q => q) 
        })
    .Union(PatientTable.Select(a => new 
        { 
            Key = "Total", 
            Total = PatientTable.Count() 
        }))
```

Comment: It still going to do two queries to db.

Comment: @vittore, Not according to SQL Profiler. It shows a single query with a `UNION ALL`. I did it against a table I already had, but I'd be happy to post the resultant query if you'd like to see it.

Comment: Actually this is interesting, after thinking about it , subquery you pass to Union returns IQueriable, so it should be executed lazily. Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

```
var report = patients
                .GroupBy(p => p.LivingSpace)
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                        Unit = g.Key,
                        Count = g.Count()
                    })
                .Union(patients
                    .Select(p => new
                    {
                        Unit = "Total",
                        Count = patients.Count
                    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work and just run one query.

```
var results = db.PatientTable
    .GroupBy(p => p.LivingSpace)
    .Select(grp => new 
        { 
            Unit = grp.Key, 
            Count = grp.Count() 
        })         
    .Union(db.PatientTable
        .GroupBy(p => 1)
        .Select(grp => new 
            { 
                Unit = "Total", 
                Count = grp.Count() 
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you got the answer, but for learning purposes, here is side by side conversion.

Your SQL (with some aliases added for better comparison)

```
SELECT P.LivingSpace, COUNT(P.*) AS Count
FROM PatientTable AS P
WHERE P.Status = 'Active'
GROUP BY P.LivingSpace

UNION ALL

SELECT 'SUM' AS LivingSpace, COUNT(P.*) AS Count
FROM PatientTable AS P
```

The same single query in LINQ

```
var query =
(
from p in db.PatientTable
where p.Status = "Active"
group p by p.LivingSpace into g
select new { LivingSpace = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
)
.Concat
(
from p in db.PatientTable
group p by "SUM" into g
select new { LivingSpace = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
);
```